# Is there a code to line break a string wrapped by span?

Tags: html, css

I have a code that passes a string into a website. The website wraps the string with span and gives me following.

```
<span style="text-overflow:ellipsis">
CHdU3mFEYP212a-CYeDSooeZtYSG  CCHdU3mFEYPasda-CYeDSooeZtSsSG-&#13;&#10;CD9czobepa4123129-CRmVpXsdf3</span>
```

If the string was wrapped in textarea we could pass code: `&#13;&#10;` and the line breaks
But it doesnt break the line for span.

- Is there a similar code for span?

Comment: wrapping `<span>` with `<pre>` might work

Comment: But I cannot edit the website code as it is third party. I just send a string into span.

Comment: Try wrapping your string with `<pre>` then.

Comment: Pass `<br>` then?

Comment: Hey @firatozcevahir I get this as output in span field  <pre>Hello there \n Hello There</pre>. And inspect as:<span style="text-overflow:ellipsis"><pre>Hello there \n Hello There</pre></span>

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
   span{
      display: block;
      width: 150px;
      word-break: wrap;
   }
```

```html
<span style="display:block; width: 250px; word-break:wrap; text-overflow:ellipsis">
CHdU3mFEYP212a-CYeDSooeZtYSG  CCHdU3mFEYPasda-CYeDSooeZtSsSG-&#13;&#10;CD9czobepa4123129-CRmVpXsdf3</span>
```

Comment: Can I add CSS to a third party website where I pass a string to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by simplly 2 method. That's it

**Method 1**

Please Use the **`<br>` tag** to enter line breaks,

```html
<span style="text-overflow:ellipsis">
CHdU3mFEYP212a-CYeDSooeZtYSG</br>  CCHdU3mFEYPasda-CYeDSooeZtSsSG-</br>CD9czobepa4123129-CRmVpXsdf3</span>
```

**Method 2**

Please use **inline CSS**

```html
<span style="text-overflow:ellipsis; width:250px; display:inline-block; word-break: break-word;">
CHdU3mFEYP212a-CYeDSooeZtYSG CCHdU3mFEYPasda-CYeDSooeZtSsSG-CD9czobepa4123129-CRmVpXsdf3</span>
```

Comment: I pass the value as a string to third party. Is there a way I can make < br > work inside a <span>"Hello</br>There"<span>. As when I pass it as a string it just displays <br> without implementing the <br> element

Comment: Can you use method 2. It is without <br> tag.

Comment: No because the website is third party and I pass a string to their site. But it shows literal <br>

Comment: Ok, Then you have to change the way to send the data.. It could be like not as a 'string'. It could be like as a 'html'. What language you are using to send data.

Comment: I am using Javascript to send the data

Comment: If you can not add inline CSS As per method 2 to resolve this issue. Then Please share your javascript syntex. We can solve this issue using javascript at the time of sending data. Please share syntex.